# Font files are being blocked by security policy

Tags: jquery, referrer

I'm learning to use flexslider with the following snippet but it can't find two font files.  I get these two errors:

> Request URL: https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/jquery/flexslider/fonts/flexslider-icon.woff
>
> Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

and

> Request URL: https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/jquery/flexslider/fonts/flexslider-icon.ttf
>
> Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

The paths have been checked and the files download when we put the address in the address bar.  Also, files seem to be called from the css code

```js
 
       $(window).load(function() {
          $('.flexslider').flexslider();
       });
```

```css
/*
 * jQuery FlexSlider v2.7.2
 * https://www.woocommerce.com/flexslider/
 *
 * Copyright 2012 WooThemes
 * Free to use under the GPLv2 and later license.
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 *
 * Contributing author: Tyler Smith (@mbmufffin)
 *
 */
/* ====================================================================================================================
 * FONT-FACE
 /* ====================================================================================================================*/
@font-face {
  font-family: 'flexslider-icon';
  src: url('fonts/flexslider-icon.eot');
  src: url('fonts/flexslider-icon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/flexslider-icon.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/flexslider-icon.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/flexslider-icon.svg#flexslider-icon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
/* ====================================================================================================================
 * RESETS
 * ====================================================================================================================*/
.flex-container a:hover,
.flex-slider a:hover {
  outline: none;
}
.slides,
.slides > li,
.flex-control-nav,
.flex-direction-nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.flex-pauseplay span {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
/* ====================================================================================================================
 * BASE STYLES
 * ====================================================================================================================*/
.flexslider {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.flexslider .slides > li {
  display: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flexslider .slides img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.flexslider .slides:after {
  content: "\0020";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
html[xmlns] .flexslider .slides {
  display: block;
}
* html .flexslider .slides {
  height: 1%;
}
.no-js .flexslider .slides > li:first-child {
  display: block;
}
/* ====================================================================================================================
 * DEFAULT THEME
 * ====================================================================================================================*/
.flexslider {
  margin: 0 0 60px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -o-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.flexslider .slides {
  zoom: 1;
}
.flexslider .slides img {
  height: auto;
  -moz-user-select: none;
}
.flex-viewport {
  max-height: 2000px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.loading .flex-viewport {
  max-height: 300px;
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .loading .flex-viewport {
    max-height: none;
  }
}
.carousel li {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.flex-direction-nav {
  *height: 0;
}
.flex-direction-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: -20px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.flex-direction-nav a:before {
  font-family: "flexslider-icon";
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '\f001';
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next:before {
  content: '\f002';
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  left: -50px;
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  right: -50px;
  text-align: right;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  opacity: 0.7;
  left: 10px;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  opacity: 0.7;
  right: 10px;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-disabled {
  opacity: 0!important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  cursor: default;
  z-index: -1;
}
.flex-pauseplay a {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
}
.flex-pauseplay a:before {
  font-family: "flexslider-icon";
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '\f004';
}
.flex-pauseplay a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-pauseplay a.flex-play:before {
  content: '\f003';
}
.flex-control-nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.flex-control-nav li {
  margin: 0 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
.flex-control-paging li a {
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  display: block;
  background: #666;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.flex-control-paging li a:hover {
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active {
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  cursor: default;
}
.flex-control-thumbs {
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  position: static;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.flex-control-thumbs li {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-control-thumbs img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  opacity: .7;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.flex-control-thumbs img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-control-thumbs .flex-active {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}
/* ====================================================================================================================
 * RESPONSIVE
 * ====================================================================================================================*/
@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 10px;
  }
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>FlexSlider</title>
   
    

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/jquery/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

   
</head>
<body>
<h1>FlexSlider</h1>
</body>
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/jquery/flexslider/demo/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
       <div class="caption">Caption one.</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/jquery/flexslider/demo/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
 <div class="caption">Caption two.</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/jquery/flexslider/demo/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
 <div class="caption">Caption three.</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Those aren't icons (images). They're fonts. Cross-domain security is well-document for font files and behavior varies by browser.

Comment: do you know how to fix the error? can you point to a reference?

Comment: [Here's a start](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy). See the CSS integration section.

Comment: Seems like your fonts should respond with another header as [stated here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy#Integration_with_CSS). You can probably change it via htaccess, or post the header via php instead...